# How to authenticate a route with passport-jwt?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I'm using `passport-jwt` and my strategy is setup like:

```
  let jwtOptions = {}
  jwtOptions.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()
  jwtOptions.secretOrKey = process.env.SECRET

  var strategy = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function (jwt_payload, next) {
    console.log('payload received', jwt_payload);
    // usually this would be a database call:
    var user = users[_.findIndex(users, { id: jwt_payload.id })];
    if (user) {
      next(null, user);
    } else {
      next(null, false);
    }
  })
  passport.use(strategy)
```

So when I POST to a `/login` route, I'm able to generate a token:

```
  var payload = { id: user.id }
  var token = jwt.sign(payload, jwtOptions.secretOrKey)
  res.json({ message: "ok", token: token })
```

But then when I try to have a route that requires a token:

```
  app.get("/secret", passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    res.json("Success! You can not see this without a token");
  })
```

My header has `Authorization: JWT [token]`

it continually returns a `401`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't show it here, do you ever call `passport.use(strategy)` with your JwtStrategy instance?

Comment: Also, show how you're formatting the header you're sending on the `GET /secret` request

Comment: @Paul - updated. I am using `passport.use(strategy)` and header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your authorization header is incorrectly formatted.  Per the [jwt-strategy docs](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt)

> `fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()` creates a new extractor that looks for the JWT in the authorization header with the scheme 'bearer'

So your header should be `Authorization: Bearer [token]`

Answer (score 2):

if you are sending token in header and using your own scheme (in your case you are using "JWT" ) you can use fromAuthHeaderWithScheme(auth_scheme) method.

you can find more detail in passport-jwt docs :

- fromAuthHeaderWithScheme(auth_scheme) creates a new extractor that looks for the JWT in the authorization header, expecting the scheme to match auth_scheme.
- fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken() creates a new extractor that looks for the JWT in the authorization header with the scheme 'bearer'

https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt