# How to get the value for the JwtStrategy option 'secretOrKey' from an environment variable

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

I'm use passport-jwt in my authentication scheme for my node app, and having a problem to get the JwtStrategy to accept an environment variable instead of a hard-coded string.

The relevant parts of the code are this:

```
const jwtOptions = {  
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET
};

const jwtLogin = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function(payload, done) {
    ...
});
```

With that I get the error "JwtStrategy requires a secret or key".

I've tried a bunch of other methods, including grabbing the env variable and returning it via a function I call as the value of the secretOrKey property, but no luck.

As I'm pretty sure storing a secret like this in a string in your app is not a great idea, and that a good option is to store it in an environment variable, I'm hoping someone has solved this.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried this and it's working fine if the environmen variable `JWT_SECRET` is there. If the variable doesn't exitst, I get the same error. Did you try a `console.log(process.env)` to see if the `JWT_SECRET` is really there? Maybe a typo somewhere?

Comment: [here another guy taking the secret from env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47657629/how-to-authenticate-a-route-with-passport-jwt)

Comment: Thanks for helping on this. I figured it out... see answer below.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so it seems the issue was related to including the config for the dotenv library.

The odd thing is that it apparently needs to be included in some cases, but not in all.

For example, I've got two files that use the secret key. One with this function:

```
function generateToken(user) {
    const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
    return jwt.sign(user, secret, {
        expiresIn: 10080 // in seconds
    });
}
```

that does NOT have the dotenv config included. The other file has this:

```
const jwtOptions = {  
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET
};
```

Without the dotenv config - `require('dotenv').config();` - it throws the error "JwtStrategy requires a secret or key". With it, it runs fine.

Comment: Interesting! Or better said : strange!  I didn't even have dotenv installed, when I tried the code from your question. In my environment it's running fine, with or without dotenv.

Comment: Wow, that is strange. I may look into this further but, hey... it's working so probably not. :)